# Creating a custom VariationalForm in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, programming, vqe

I would like to use the built-in Qiskit `VQE()` function, with my own variational form. What is the proper way to define it? I was expecting `var_form` to be simply a function returning an object of type `QuantumCircuit` for a particular set of parameters (that's how it's done in Pyquil).

More precisely: how do I manually create an instance of the `VariationalForm` class which would correspond to preparing the desired program for a given set of parameters?

So far my understanding is that I have to do smth like that:

```
 class my_var_form(VariationalForm):
    def construct_circuit(self,
                          parameters: Union[List[float], np.ndarray],
                          q: Optional[QuantumRegister] = None) -> NoReturn:
        circuit = QuantumCircuit(q)
        ...
        return circuit
```

Is this the proper way to do things?

**CLARIFICATION**

Let us define a function which would generate a Qiskit circuit for an arbitrary parameter of type `float`:

```
def black_box( param : float ):
    qc = qskt.QuantumCircuit( 1 )
    qc.u1( np.sqrt( param ), 0 )
    return qc
```

`np.sqrt()` was chosen as a toy example, one could equally well replace it with any fucntion defined on `float`s. To make sure that the function makes sense, one can do this:

```
job = execute( black_box( 1. ), get_backend('qasm_simulator') ) # Works fine
```

Now, let us try to define a `VariationalForm` which will use our `black_box` function:

```
class my_var_form( VariationalForm ):
    def __init__(self, numpar, numq, bnds) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self._num_parameters = numpar
        self._num_qubits = numq
        self._bounds = bnds
        pass
    def construct_circuit(self,
                          parameters: Union[List[float], np.ndarray],
                          q: Optional[qskt.QuantumRegister] = None) -> NoReturn:
    circuit = black_box( parameters[0] )
    return circuit
```

However, the following code fails to work:

```
var_form_instance = my_var_form( 1, 1, [[-2., 2]] )
vqe = VQE( WeightedPauliOperator( [1., Pauli([0.],[0.])] ),
           var_form_instance,
           L_BFGS_B(),
           np.array([0])
         )
```

With the following error:

```
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Parameter which has no callable sqrt method
```

The problem is that Qiskit no matter what wants to use its built-in `Parameter` class which is based on the `sympy` package.

How can I overcome this issue? Or is there absolutely no way I could use the built-in `VQE` function without dealing with `Parameter` class?

My question arises from the fact that I use an external library to generate circuits which I then convert to Qiskit format. Thus, I have a function which returns a Qiskit circuit for a set of real parameters. I would like the Qiskit `VQE()` function to use my own `black_box()` function for generating the quantum circuit on each step of the minimization.

(Alternatively, I could just not use `VQE()` at all, and simply run the classical minimizer myself, only using Qiskit for evaluating the expectation value of the Hamiltonian on each step... but apparently there's no built-in function for calculating the expectation value neither of a Pauli string, nor even of individual Pauli operators! See my question [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12080/evaluating-expectation-values-of-operators-in-qiskit): to my understanding `SnapshotExpectationValue()` is an unphysical method, and does not allow one to calculate expectation values of Pauli strings using sampling on real devices.)

Comment: I see, no there is currently no way to not use the `Parameter` class. That used to be possible but was removed because there was no use-case where `Parameter` did not work. You open [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/issues) to address this :)

However there are ways to calculate expectation values, its actually quite easy. Check out [this notebook](https://github.com/dongreenberg/aqua_talks/blob/master/Understanding%20Aqua%27s%20Operator%20Flow.ipynb).

Answer (score 5):

You can plug any parameterized `QuantumCircuit` into the VQE. 
Parameterized means it contains `Parameter` objects e.g. as rotation angles. For instance

```
from qiskit.circuit import QuantumCircuit, ParameterVector
from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import VQE

params = ParameterVector(3)
wavefunction = QuantumCircuit(3)
wavefunction.ry(params[0], 0)
wavefunction.ry(params[1], 1)
wavefunction.ry(params[2], 2)

vqe = VQE(var_form=wavefunction, ...)
```

I'd suggest you to have a look at the [circuit library](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/circuit_library.html), especially the N-local circuits as e.g. the [`TwoLocal` circuit](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.TwoLocal.html).

[This notebook](https://github.com/Cryoris/notebooks/blob/master/Circuit%20library%20%26%20native%20circuits.ipynb) explains this in more detail and shows some of the new functionality of Qiskit 0.19.0 concerning the circuit library and how it interacts with Aqua.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it was the `ParameterVector` thing which I was unaware of, and which works as a simple solution.

Comment: Could you please suggest a solution not relying on `Parameter` objects? I would like to use a 'black box' function which takes as input some numbers and returns a `QuantumCircuit` object.

Comment: I also have the following solution: instead of using the built-in Qiskit `VQE()` function, I could simply use scipy minimize, if I manage to write a function which would calculate the expectation value of a given operator in a given state. How do I do this in Qiskit?

Comment: Did you have a look at the notebook? There the `TwoLocal` object is presented which takes input parameters and returns a `QuantumCircuit`. Is that what you're looking for? 

About computing the expectation value: That turns into another topic, maybe you could open another question for this? I'm sure more people are interested in this!

Comment: Thanks, asked [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12080/evaluating-expectation-values-of-operators-in-qiskit). As for `TwoLocal`: it seems like it's only capable of implementing circuits of specific forms. While I wanted `var_form` to generate arbitrary gate sets depending on the parameters provided as `float`s, potentially using some external libraries (which are unaware of the `Parameter` class).

Comment: Could you be more specific of what functionality you're looking for? Maybe you could post an example. Are you looking for a circuit with random structure, or a certain pattern, or something else?

Comment: @Cryosis, I'm using an external library which generates a quantum circuit, provided a set of numerical parameters. Then I would like to simulate it using Qiskit. It works perfectly for a fixed set of parameters. But it doesn't work with the built-in Qiskit `VQE()` function, because it wants the parameters to be not just floats, but `Parameter` class objects.

Comment: Could you share the code to see how these circuits are generated? To use the VQE in Qiskit you need to be able to change the parameters of the circuit. Either by having `Parameter` objects in there, or by wrapping it into a `VariationalForm` object and providing a `construct_circuit(params)` method.

Comment: please see the update to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

You basically have to construct:

1. A parametrized circuit
2. Objective function which returns the cost
3. Minimize the cost with the classical optimizer eg. COBYLA

Example:
https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-applications/vqe-molecules.html#Example-with-a-Single-Qubit-Variational-Form

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried, but probably you can create your own type which extends ParameterExpression type(class) and define your custom function (in this case sqrt) so that it can be applied on the Parameter obj during the training/testing phase. Paramter objects can only evaluate basic arithmetic operations, which probably you might have already observed.

May be I will try and let you know if it works. But looks possible.

Comment: I ended up creating my own parameterized function, inside which I'm calculating expectation values, and sending it to scipy.minimize. IMHO Qiskit's VQE function is too much tied to quantum chemistry and doesn't provide enough flexibility to work with general fermionic systems.