# Evaluating expectation values of operators in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, programming

I'm wondering how in Qiskit one can calculate the expectation value of an operator given as a `WeightedPauli` (or, at least, of a single `Pauli` operator...) in a certain state (given as a `QuantumCircuit` object ⁠— meaning that the actual state is the result of the action of this circuit on the computational basis state). I would like the inputs of such a procedure to be `float`s, not `Parameter`s (it is an essential requirement — I'm using an external library to form the circuit for each set of parameters, and then converting it gate-by-gate to Qiskit format).

This would be useful if, say, we wanted to manually implement VQE, and for that needed a function calculating the expectation value of the Hamiltonian on a quantum computer. More importantly, we would need this for implementing generalizations of VQE, such as subspace search.

I guess, `PauliBasisChange` may be involved...

Comment: https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.snapshot_expectation_value.html ?

Comment: @Simon, to my understanding, this is an unphysical method. I'm looking for smth that would work on an anctual device, based on sampling.

Comment: The `SnapshotExpectationValue` is developed to be fast. It computes the expectation value via matrix multiplication, not using shots.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Note:** This post is a bit older and Qiskit Aqua is now deprecated. Replace all occurences of `qiskit.aqua.operators` with `qiskit.opflow` to be compatible with Qiskit Terra 0.17.0 and above.

The operators in Qiskit Aqua allow the evaluation of expectation values both exactly (via matrix multiplication) or on shot-based sampling (closer to real quantum computers). The basic principle is the same both times, it only differs in how the expectation value is evaluated in the end.

First, you need to define the operator $O$ you're interested in and the state $|\psi\rangle$ with respect to which you want to compute the expecation value. So we're looking for
$$
E = \langle\psi|O|\psi\rangle.
$$
In the code below we have $O$ = `op` and $|\psi\rangle$ = `psi`.
See also there for your use-case of a `WeightedPauliOperator`.

```
# you can define your operator as circuit
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.z(0)
circuit.z(1)
op = CircuitOp(circuit)  # and convert to an operator

# or if you have a WeightedPauliOperator, do
op = weighted_pauli_op.to_opflow()

# but here we'll use the H2-molecule Hamiltonian
from qiskit.aqua.operators import X, Y, Z, I
op =  (-1.0523732 * I^I) + (0.39793742 * I^Z) + (-0.3979374 * Z^I) \
    + (-0.0112801 * Z^Z) + (0.18093119 * X^X)

# define the state you w.r.t. which you want the expectation value
psi = QuantumCircuit(2)
psi.x(0) 
psi.x(1)

# convert to a state
psi = CircuitStateFn(psi)
```

There are now different ways to evaluate the expectation value. The straightforward, "mathematical", approach would be to take the adjoint of $|\psi\rangle$ (which is $\langle\psi|$) and multiply with $O$ and then $|\psi\rangle$ to get the expectation. You can actually do exactly this in Qiskit:

```
# easy expectation value, use for small systems only!
print('Math:', psi.adjoint().compose(op).compose(psi).eval().real)
```

to get

```
Exact: -1.0636533199999998
```

This is only suitable for small systems though.

To use the simulators, and the also get the shot-based result, you can use the `PauliExpectation` (shots), `AerPauliExpectation` (exact) or `MatrixExpectation` (exact).
Here's how to do it:

```
from qiskit import Aer
from qiskit.aqua import QuantumInstance
from qiskit.aqua.operators import PauliExpectation, CircuitSampler, StateFn

# define your backend or quantum instance (where you can add settings)
backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator') 
q_instance = QuantumInstance(backend, shots=1024)

# define the state to sample
measurable_expression = StateFn(op, is_measurement=True).compose(psi) 

# convert to expectation value
expectation = PauliExpectation().convert(measurable_expression)  

# get state sampler (you can also pass the backend directly)
sampler = CircuitSampler(q_instance).convert(expectation) 

# evaluate
print('Sampled:', sampler.eval().real)
```

which yields

```
Sampled: -1.0530518430859401
```

This result varies if you execute multiple times.

For comparison, here the other methods to evaluate the expecation value

```
expectation = AerPauliExpectation().convert(measurable_expression)
sampler = CircuitSampler(backend).convert(expectation)  
print('Snapshot:', sampler.eval().real) 

expectation = MatrixExpectation().convert(measurable_expression)
sampler = CircuitSampler(backend).convert(expectation)  
print('Matrix:', sampler.eval().real)
```

which produces

```
Snapshot: -1.06365328
Matrix: -1.06365328
```

I hope that clarifies how to compute the expectation value!

Comment: Thanks! A couple of questions regarding the sampler solution: 1) Will it work if I replace the qasm backend with a real device? 2) Where do I specify the number of samples?

Comment: 1) Yes it should, it can use the `QuantumInstance` like the other Aqua algorithms use too. 2) By passing a `QuantumInstance`, I updated the answer above. 
Could you accept the answer, if your question was answered? :) It helps so others can see that this is resolved and a solution was found.

Comment: What kinds of optimizations does Qikist do while using this method? For example, does it split the `WeightedPauliSum` into commuting sets, in order to reduce the number of measurements?

Comment: Following my previous comment - are there any circuit optimizations performed using the `transpiler` in this code, or should I first do that manually?

Comment: Also, the line `q_instance = QuantumInstance(backend, shots = shots)` generates the following warning, if the real hardware is used: `WARNING - The skip Qobj validation does not work for IBMQ provider. Disable it.`. Do you know why, and how to avoid it?

Comment: Do `QuantumInstance(backend, shots=1024, skip_qobj_validation=False)` but its just a warning and does not influence your code.

Comment: Got it! Please see also my two comments before.

Comment: The Paulis are grouped in the `PauliExpectation`, it has an argument `group_paulis` which can be set to False (True by default). The transpiler does some light circuit optimization by default, you can set `optimization_level=3` in the quantum instance for the heavy optimization. See the [expectation docs](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.aqua.operators.expectations.PauliExpectation.html?highlight=pauliexpectation) and [quantum instance docs](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.aqua.QuantumInstance.html?highlight=quantuminstance#qiskit.aqua.QuantumInstance).

Comment: Awesome, thanks!!

Comment: @Cryosis, please see my bug report [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/issues/1034). It looks like this method does not work with circuits obtained via `evolve()` or `initialize`.

Comment: one more question ^_^. If I were measuring Pauli operators in a brute-force way, by manually doing sampling term-by-term, it would be trivial to implement [this](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-quantum-hardware/measurement-error-mitigation.html) way of measurement error mitigation. Is there a way I could implement this functionality within your approach?

Comment: Here's my guess: `q_instance = QuantumInstance(backend, shots=1024, measurement_error_mitigation_cls = CompleteMeasFitter(), measurement_error_mitigation_shots = 1024)`. Will the error filter matrix be calculated at the moment of initializing the `q_instance`? (I want to use the `q_instance` for evaluating multiple Pauli operators, and not to calculate the filter matrix again each time.)

Comment: Almost right, in principle it should be `qi = QuantumInstance(backend=backend, shots=8000, measurement_error_mitigation_cls=CompleteMeasFitter, measurement_error_mitigation_shots=8000)` followed by `qi.execute(circuit)`.

Comment: the circuit I'm using was obtained by the procedure suggested [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/issues/1034), so I have the following code: `circuit_fixed = QuantumCircuit( circuit.num_qubits )`; 
`circuit_fixed.append( circuit.to_instruction(), list( range( circuit.num_qubits ) ) )`. However, as I'm calling `q_instance.execute(circuit_fixed)`, I get the following error: `..\measurement_error_mitigation.py", line 129, in build_measurement_error_mitigation_qobj
    raise AquaError("The measured qubit list can not be [].")`. Do you have an idea what this can be?

Comment: @Cryosis, how can I calculate the exact expectation value using the `ibmq_qasm_simulator`, instead of using my own CPU? I asked this question [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/16050/calculating-exact-expectation-values-on-ibmq-qasm-simulator).

Comment: @Cryoris, I am using the ```PauliExpectation``` method you outlined above on the IBMQ backend. I am finding that it works very well. However, it seems that script execution time increases drastically for the number of qubits. For nqubits=4 it takes ~1.5s, for nqubits=6 it takes ~50s, and for nqubits=8 it hangs for a long time (at least 30 min). I have found that it hangs on the ```PauliExpectation().convert(measurable_expression)``` line. Is there a way I can speed this up?

Comment: Depends on your `measurable_expression`. If possible, the operator should consist only of Paulis and sums of Paulis. As soon as you have matrices, it will take a very long time.

Comment: @Cryoris, Apart from the Pauli matrices, my circuit is composed of only $R_y, C_x, H$ gates. Given that, is there anything I can do to reduce the processing time?

Comment: Could you maybe open an issue on GitHub? It’ll be easier to discuss there, maybe you could add a minimal example :)

Comment: @Cryoris, I have opened an issue: https://github.com/thegiantspaceman/VQLS/issues/1 If you run the "VQLS_github.py" script it should work fine for 'nqubit=4' but for 'nqubit=8' you will see it getting hung as I described.

Comment: @Cryoris, Thanks for your help so far, have you had a chance to look at the github issue yet?