# Calculating exact expectation values on ibmq_qasm_simulator

Tags: programming, qiskit

In order to calculate the exact expectation value of a Pauli operator in some state using local `qasm_simulator`, I do

```
psi = qiskit.aqua.operators.state_fns.CircuitStateFn( circuit )
expect = psi.adjoint().compose( weighted_pauli.to_opflow() ).compose( psi ).eval().real
```

I would like to run this calculation using `ibmq_quantum_simulator`. In all the examples I found online (see e.g. [this one](https://quantumcomputinguk.org/cnot)), `ibmq_quantum_simulator` is used to simulate sampling with some number of shots. How do I use it with `shots = None`, similarly to the code above?

Comment: You can't do `shots=None` to get the expectation value, this doesn't really make much sense; there are two ways to do the calculation of the expectation value: the exact way (the code you put) or with shot-based sampling, meaning using the simulator. I strongly advise you to look at this answer, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12080/evaluating-expectation-values-of-operators-in-qiskit/12210#12210, really well-written about how to calculate the expectation value with Qiskit. As you can see the simulator is used for the second way of calculation.

Comment: You did not answer my question. The code I provided does the statevector calculation using my local CPU. How do I run this calculation using the `ibmq_quantum_simulator`?

Comment: @mavzolej why not just write your own function to calculate the expectation from the extracted counts you get from the experiment?

Comment: Which counts?.. I want to do the statevector calculation, which does not involve any counts, and only uses the statevector representation of a quantum state and the unitary matrix representation of the quantum circuit.

Comment: @mavzolej I thought `ibmq_qasm_simulator` can only do shot based simulation... can you actually extract the statevector from it? Didn't know that was possible.

Comment: Well, by definition `ibmq_qasm_simulator` samples from the exact probability distribution, which is probably calculated using the statevector representation. I was hoping I can access it, but I don't know if it is possible...

Comment: (This page)[https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/docs/manage/simulator/] says that the underlying code of `imbq_qasm_simulator` is similar to that of `qasm_simulator`. And in `qasm_simulator` one can choose `method = statevector`.