# Why is CircuitSampler ignoring number of shots if backend is a statevector_simulator?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-state

I am calculating the expectation value of an operator using the `CircuitSampler` class as mentioned [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/12210/19840). Now, I was getting exact same result for the expectation values even when I specified different number of shots. It turns out that in the method `convert` of `CircuitSampler` ignores the number of shots if the `backend` is a `statevector_simulator`. Why is that the case? Also, what is the difference if `backend` is a `statevector` or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is called *"Aer fast expectation"*. It is enabled by default if operator primitives are Paulis and the used backend is Aer Qasm backend. It has the advantage of being fast. However, if you pass a noise model to the simulator, it will be ignored.

If you are using [`ExpectationFactory`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.opflow.expectations.ExpectationFactory.html) you can disable this behavior by setting `include_custom` to `False` so that [`PauliExpectation`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.opflow.expectations.PauliExpectation.html) will be used instead of [`AerPauliExpectation`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.opflow.expectations.AerPauliExpectation.html)

```
observables = [
    X^X,
    Z^I,
    Z^Z,
]

circuit_sampler = CircuitSampler(quantum_instance)
exp_converter = ExpectationFactory.build(observables[0], None, include_custom = False) # <== here

list_op = ListOp([StateFn(obs, is_measurement = True).compose(StateFn(circuit)) for obs in observables])

observables_expect = exp_converter.convert(list_op)
observables_expect_sampled = circuit_sampler.convert(observables_expect)

observables_results = np.real(observables_expect_sampled.eval())
print(observables_results)
```

Comment: I also notice that specifying  `statevector_simulator`  as the backend returns much more accurate results than specifying `aer_simulator` in this case. Why is that the case?

Comment: Does statevector_simulator with CircuitSampler simulate a quantum computer at all? Does it simply do a matrix vector multiplication to get the expectation value?

Answer (score 5):

The Statevector is a vector of length $2^n$ (where you have $n$ qubits) in which the square of each element's absolute value gives you the probability of getting that bit pattern.  So, for example, $[\frac{\sqrt3}4, \frac{\sqrt5}4, \frac{\sqrt6}4, \frac{\sqrt2}4]$ indicates that you have a
$\frac{3}{16}$ chance of getting $|00\rangle$, a $\frac5{16}$ chance of getting $|01\rangle$, etc.  This is a calculation that can only be done by a simulator keeping track of every possible state, and not by an actual quantum device with $n$ qubits.

Since a statevector simulator knows the exact odds of every possible result (save for floating point errors), it can give a precise answer.

Simulators that return shots rather than statevectors often generate a statevector internally, and then use a method similar to `Statevector.sample_memory(shots)` to emulate taking quantum measurements on a statevector.  The results look less clean and more like coin tossing.

Comment: Does this mean that using `statevector_simulator` with `CircuitSampler` doesn't simulate a quantum computer at all? Does it simply do a matrix vector multiplication to get the expectation value?

Comment: I've never implemented a simulator myself, but I suspect this is what all of them do.  There is no other way (that I know of) to simulate a quantum computer classically.