# How does Qiskit CircuitSampler class calculate expectation values of operators?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-quantum-devices

I have been using `Qiskit` `CircuitSampler` class to calculate the expectation values of operators as described [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/12210/19840). Now it turns out that when it is used with `statevector_simulator` it [ignores](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/29275/19840) the number of shots specified. How does `CircuitSampler` calculate expectation value of an operator in this case and otherwise?