# Can someone explain the behavior called "Aer fast expectation" of Qiskit simulators?

Tags: simulation, qiskit

Earlier I asked a [question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/29275/why-is-circuitsampler-ignoring-number-of-shots-if-backend-is-a-statevector-simul) on why `statevector_simulator` ignores the number of shots when calculating the expectation value of an operator using `CircuitSampler`. This was attributed to something called the "Aer fast expectation". Can someone explain it in more detail? Also, what should I do if I want to use a noise model with `CircuitSampler` and `statevector_simulator`?

As said in an answer to the linked question, this behavior ignores a noise model if passed to the simulator. How do I make sure that the `VQE` class in Qiskit does not ignore the noise model when using `statevector_simulator`?