# Evaluate a gradient with a specific backend (Qiskit)

Tags: qiskit, vqe

I'm following the [tutorial on gradients](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stable/0.38/tutorials/operators/02_gradients_framework.html) in Qiskit. Suppose I have the following:

```
# Instantiate the quantum state
a = Parameter('a')
b = Parameter('b')
q = QuantumRegister(1)
qc = QuantumCircuit(q)
qc.h(q)
qc.rz(a, q[0])
qc.rx(b, q[0])
params = [a, b]

# Instantiate the Hamiltonian observable
H = 0.5 * X - 1 * Z

# Combine the Hamiltonian observable and the state
op = ~StateFn(H) @ CircuitStateFn(primitive=qc, coeff=1.)

value_dict = { a: np.pi / 4, b: np.pi}

state_grad = Gradient(grad_method='param_shift').convert(operator=op, params=params)

state_grad_assigned = state_grad.assign_parameters(value_dict)
```

Here `state_grad_assigned` is an object of type `ListOp`. If I call `state_grad_assigned.eval()`, it will return the exact gradient vector of $\langle \psi(a, b) | H | \psi(a, b) \rangle$. However, I would like to evaluate that expression using a noisy backend, e.g. one from `AerSimulator`. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run on a simulator (or backend) you can use the `CircuitSampler`. For the details of how that class can be used you can check out this related question: [Evaluating expectation values of operators in Qiskit](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12080/evaluating-expectation-values-of-operators-in-qiskit/12210#12210)

In your case, your code would need to be modified something like

```
from qiskit_aer.backends import AerSimulator
from qiskit.opflow import CircuitSampler, AerPauliExpectation

simulator = AerSimulator()
sampler = CircuitSampler(simulator)

state_grad = # ... like you had it before

# now use the CircuitSampler to evaluate the gradient
# for efficiency: don't manually bind the parameters, but let the sampler do it!
sampled = sampler.convert(state_grad, value_dict)

# now call eval to evaluate the sampled circuits
result = sampled.eval()
```